# Mean of 2-dimensional data points

Tags: r, mean, k-means, euclidean-distance

I have these data points:

```
> a1 = c(2,10)
> a2 = c(2,5)
> a3 = c(8,4)
```

And I'd like to find the 2 dimensional mean (edit: Centroid) of those data points with r.

I have tried the following:

```
>mean(c(a1,a2,a3))
```

but it only gives me a one-dimensional mean value.  How can I get the mean of the points?

Comment: Sequentially name variables are terrible and ungeneralizable. You should put your coordinates in a data frame or a matrix, with one column for the first coordinate and one column for the second coordinate. Then `colMeans(your_dat)` will do what you want.

Comment: colMeans(rbind(a1,a2,a3))

Comment: Can you define "2 dimensional mean" more precisely? You are not, perhaps, thinking of the centroid ("centre of mass" of the points) ?

Comment: @neilfws I'm referring to the centroid.  I didn't know it was called that. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3 points always-

```
centroid <- (a1 + a2 + a3) / 3
```